# Regular expression to identify text between semi-colons that contains comma and spaces

Tags: regex, powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to identify some texts that contains comma(,) and white spaces(\s+) in a csv that is semi-colon(;) separated. Sample csv entries are as followed:

```
09/03/2023;13;P;1210/2003 (OJ L169);2003-07-08;http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF;IRQ;(UNSC RESOLUTION 1483);;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;14;13;1210/2003 (OJ L169);2003-07-08;http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF;IRQ;1937-04-28;al-Awja, near Tikrit;IRQ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;EU.27.28
09/03/2023;20;P;1210/2003 (OJ L169);2003-07-08;http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF;IRQ;(Saddam's second son);26;20;1210/2003 (OJ L169);2003-07-08;http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF;IRQ;Hussein Al-Tikriti;Qusay;Saddam;Qusay Saddam Hussein Al-Tikriti;M;;Oversaw Special Republican Guard, Special Security Organisation, and Republican Guard;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;EU.39.56
```

In the sample data I am trying to extract following texts:

```
al-Awja, near Tikrit
Oversaw Special Republican Guard, Special Security Organisation, and Republican Guard
```

Both the instances of target texts have comma(,) in it and that is creating issue when trying to convert the semi-colon(;) separated file into a comma(,) separated file as it adds extra columns for existing commas(,) in the string.

So far I have following regular expression that is taking me to the required texts. However, I am unable to retrieve entire string using this.

Regex: `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)([,])(\s+)([A-Za-z0-9-]+)`

Please help.

Comment: Well, `(?<![^;])[\w-]+(?:\s+[\w-]+)*(?:\s*,\s*[\w-]+(?:\s+[\w-]+)*)+(?![^;])` might work. The `(?<![^;])\w+(?:-\w+)*(?:\s+\w+(?:-\w+)*)*(?:\s*,\s*\w+(?:-\w+)*(?:\s+\w+(?:-\w+)*)*)+(?![^;])` is more precise probably.

Comment: Does data have a header row?  You should be using Import-CSV and getting dat by the header name.

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler to split your input lines into fields and then use a relative simple regex to filter those fields by the characters of interest:

```bash
# Assume that $lines contains the lines of the input file, such as
# obtained via Get-Content
$lines -split ';' -match ' .*,|,.* '
```

This outputs those fields that contain *both* a space *and* a comma (`,`), yielding the output shown in your question.

If you only care about commas, `-match ','` will do.

---

Taking a step back:

You can read your file with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) `-Delimiter ';'` and export it to a regular, `,`-separated CSV with [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv), which does *not* require special handling of fields with embedded `,` chars., because these cmdlets automatically enclose the field values in `"..."` (double quotes), which allows the fields to contain `,`.

If your input file happens to lack a *header* row (a first line that contains column names), you'll have to supply one yourself, via the `-Header` parameter.